# Length of the path traced along a curve

Tags: calculus, integration, curves

I have the following curve equation:

$$r(t) = \frac{c^2}{a}\cos^3(t)i + \frac{c^2}{b}\sin^3(t)j, \quad c^2 = a^2 - b^2, \quad 0 \leq t \leq 2\pi$$

I need to find the path traced by a particle moving along this path during the interval of $t$ specified. It is quite clear that the path traced is the integral of speed $\lVert r'(t) \rVert$ over the interval $[0, 2\pi]$. Thus, I first find the speed:

$$\lVert r'(t)\rVert = \frac{3c^2\cos t \sin t}{2ab}\sqrt{b^2 + c^2\sin^2t}$$

which seems to be continuous everywhere on $[0, 2\pi]$, and the target integral is then:

$$\Lambda(0, 2\pi) = \frac{3}{2ab}\int_{0}^{2\pi}2c^2\cos t \sin t \sqrt{b^2 + c^2\sin^2t} dt $$ which can then be evaluated with the substitution. However, the integral I get is:

$$\frac{3}{2ab}\sqrt{b^2 + c^2\sin^2t}^3 + C$$

If I use this with its limits $2\pi$ and $0$, the arc length is 0!!! I plotted the curve, and this path DOES exist, and seems continuous. What am I doing wrong here?

PS. The answer in Apostol 14.13#4 seems to be $\frac{4(a^3 - b^3)}{ab}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you [plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5BCos%5Bt%5D*Sin%5Bt%5D*Sqrt%5B16%2B9*Sin%5Bt%5D%5E2%5D%2C+%7Bt%2C0%2C2*Pi%7D%5D) your $\|r'(t)\|$ for $t \in (0,2\pi)$, you will see it takes on negative values and is $\pi$-periodic, so $\int_0^{2\pi} \|r'(t)\|dt = 0$ as you have found.

I suggest using symmetry to claim that
$$
L = 4\int_0^{\pi/2} \left\|r'(t) \right\| dt
$$

Comment: Cool thx I found the blunder due to your comment :D When finding the length, I forgot that $\sin t \cos t$ can be negative, so requires an absolute value, and integration interval split ^^

Comment: No, the length of the curve is the integral of speed (per Apostol's proof), which is easier to find here. The above^ is only when you have a functional form $y  = r(x)$

Comment: Actually, when you have $x(t)$ and $y(t)$, where $x$ and $y$ are position functions, the length is $L = \displaystyle\int_{t_0}^{t_1} \sqrt{\left(\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dt}\right)^2} \, \mathrm dt$, but $v_x^2+v_y^2 = v^2$ (and taking the square root gives speed) anyway, so they're the same. (Just wanted to point that out.)

Comment: @John thanks, deleted remark